# How to collect instances of XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, object, xmlhttprequest, instance

I want to collect all instances of XMLHttpRequest

Here is my code:

```
var array = [];
var orig_XMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest;
XMLHttpRequest = function() {
    array.push(this);
    return new orig_XMLHttpRequest();
}

var ajax_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

but because "return new orig_XMLHttpRequest();"

so array[0] is not I actually want (ajax_request), I think in array[0] is an empty object?

Because I will override XMLHttpRequest and it has to use 'new' keyword and then return, so I can't get the correct "this".....

Is there any way to get all instances of XMLHttpRequest?

thanks

Comment: This could be an XY problem. What is reason for collecting instances? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If you want to get the instance, just get the instance before you return it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to push the created instance to your array:

```
var array = [];
var orig_XMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest;
XMLHttpRequest = function() {
    var xhr = new orig_XMLHttpRequest();
    array.push(xhr);
    return xhr;
}

var ajax_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Comment: wow it works!! thanks!! but can you explain that why xhr will be ajax_request? I don't understand....

Comment: I would love to but I can't understand what it is that *you* don't understand

Comment: I'm a newbie lol, many concepts are not very clear...just because return xhr and then assign to ajax_request, so ajax_request is point to xhr, am I right?

Comment: @chenyuxian - yes, that's right. when a "constructor" function (any function that's called with `new`) returns an object (*any* object), that object becomes the result of the construction expression and the "`this`" that was created as part of the `new` statement is discarded.